# Get-ADUser Filter error when adding a string criteria containing a variable

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get only active AD Users in AD which satisfies below conditions:

- samaccountname is not null
- mail is not null
- mail ends with a domain, in this case what is contained in @oldDomain variable

As a demo, I have also filter by only a samaccountname. Below is not working:

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter {(samaccountname -ne "null") -and (samaccountname -eq "TestUserPruebasSI") -and (Enabled -eq "true") -and (mail -ne "null") -and "mail -like '*$oldDomain'"}
```

The culprit is the last criteria "mail -like '*$oldDomain'". If I remove it then query Get-ADUser works.

So how can I solve this?

Comment: `"mail -like '*$oldDomain'"` -> `mail -like "*$oldDomain"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using below works:

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter "samaccountname -ne 'null' -and samaccountname -eq 'TestUserPruebasSI' -and Enabled -eq 'true' -and mail -ne 'null' -and mail -like '*$oldDomain'"
```

Comment: You can safely skip the `samaccountname -ne 'null'` and `mail -ne 'null'` parts, because later on you filter on these properties to have a value to compare against. Besides.. is it possible for a user to NOT have a `SamAccountName` ??